# How to build webkit on windows 7 64 bit machine

Tags: webkit

I have already build webkit on windows 7, 32 bit. Now I am trying to build it on windows  7,64 bit, but while I am trying to update the source tree using script "update-webkit", I am getting the below error:

```
Updating OpenSource
Can't locate HTTP/Date.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 .) at /cygdrive/d/source/WebKit-r157864.tar/WebKit-r157864/Tools/Scripts/update-webkit-dependency line 39.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /cygdrive/d/source/WebKit-r157864.tar/WebKit-r157864/Tools/Scripts/update-webkit-dependency line 39.
Died at Tools/Scripts/update-webkit-auxiliary-libs line 40.
Died at ./update-webkit line 84.
```

So can anybody help me to resolve this problem and tell the steps to build the webkit open source code successfully. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try "cpan HTTP::Date"? Hope this work.
Maybe joining the WebKit mailing list will help. https://lists.webkit.org/mailman/listinfo/webkit-help